# Importing a EOS private key into an Android or iOS wallet

Tags: wallet, keys, public-key

I generated a EOS private key via the command line and would like to import this private key into my Android or iOS. Which mobile wallets support importing of EOS private keys?

Comment: mobile wallet is not a suitable term in case of EOS. But you can  use  eoslynx, first you should have a account on EOS. if not you have to create one.